# OpenForm with the condition based on textbox in report?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my report (in MS Access), I'm trying to have a form open and go to a specific record upon opening. I want to to the record where the orthForm in the query is equal to the orthForm textbox being clicked. I have:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FwordFullQuery", , , "orthForm = " & (Me.orthForm)
```

But then it just asks for a parameter, which annoyingly is **equal to the value** I want to pass as the parameter! The parameter is named like the text written in my TextBox.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `orthForm` the exact name of the / a field in your table? It it is not, access will ask you to input a value for it, because it cannot resolve it as a part of the SQL-Statement. What exactly is access asking for? For `orthForm` or `Me.orthForm`?

Comment: It's the name of the textbox being slicked on (renamed to orthFormBox now though) in the report, and orthForm is the value it's showing (and thus the value when going back into the form)

Comment: It should read `DoCmd.OpenForm "FwordFullQuery", , , "theFieldInYourTable = " & (Me.theTextFieldInYourForm)` - did you make sure that is the case?

Comment: It's exactly like that, yes. Then when it's clicked on, a prompt pops up asking for a parameter, and the text in this box is the value OF the paramater I want to pass.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the parameter you pass in `'`:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FwordFullQuery", , , "orthForm = '" & (Me.orthForm) & "'"
```

Otherwise your final statment would look something like

```
SELECT bla FROM table WHERE orthForm = myText
```

logically access will try to resolve `myText`  because it thinks it is a field name or parameter or something - which it isn't. Wrapping it in `'` will result in

```
SELECT bla FROM table WHERE orthForm = 'myText'
```

which access just can execute as a valid SQL statement.

Comment: With the proviso that orthForm must not contain any single quotes. BTW the brackets are completely unnecessary.